# Counting consecutive events on pandas dataframe by their index

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I'm trying to use dataframe to select events. Let's say I have only two kinds of events: 1, -1 and the following dataframe:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'ev':[1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1]})
```

with:

```
a[a['ev']>0]
```

I can select only the 1 events. Now I would like to count how many consecutive events I have; in this case I would like to get `[2,3]`

The point is: how to get the list (or the series) of the indexes involved in `a[a['ev']>0]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add `.index` to return a list of the indexes

```
In [43]: a=pd.DataFrame({'ev':[1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1]})

In [44]: b = list(a[a['ev']>0].index)

In [45]: b
Out[45]: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Your result, `[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]`, is not the result sought - `[2, 3]`.

Comment: The result sought doesn't make any sense.. given his condition, the postions 2 and 3 correspond with a -1 and 1 respectively, and therefore the condition is not met by his result... I am showing him how to get a list of the indexes based on a condition, he can edit the condition to his heart's desire

Comment: This answer is misleading given the title. It relies on the fact that values are only -1, 1 (which I see is in the question). Either this answer needs to change to match the title, or the title needs to change to say consecutive 1's or -1's.

Comment: The last line of the question is: The point is: how to get the list (or the series) of the indexes involved in a[a['ev']>0]? - the answer does this. @cgnorthcutt

Comment: @scott - the title says events but it should say '-1' and '1' as the solutions here don't work for other types of events like 3 and 4 for example. The title is more broad then the content.

Comment: @cgnorthcutt sure - but since the answer is accepted and it's 4 years old - i'm not going to change it.  people can read the content of the question, you can submit another answer for just the title if you like