# Pandas: conditional rolling count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series that looks the following:

```
   col
0  B
1  B
2  A
3  A
4  A
5  B
```

It's a time series, therefore the index is ordered by time.

For each row, I'd like to count how many times the value has appeared consecutively, i.e.:

Output:

```
   col count
0  B   1
1  B   2
2  A   1 # Value does not match previous row => reset counter to 1
3  A   2
4  A   3
5  B   1 # Value does not match previous row => reset counter to 1
```

I found 2 related questions, but I can't figure out how to "write" that information as a new column in the DataFrame, for each row (as above). Using rolling_apply does not work well.

Related:

[Counting consecutive events on pandas dataframe by their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264291/counting-consecutive-events-on-pandas-dataframe-by-their-index)

[Finding consecutive segments in a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358567/finding-consecutive-segments-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 76):

I think there is a nice way to combine the solution of @chrisb and @CodeShaman (As it was pointed out CodeShamans solution counts total and not consecutive values).

```
  df['count'] = df.groupby((df['col'] != df['col'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1

  col  count
0   B      1
1   B      2
2   A      1
3   A      2
4   A      3
5   B      1
```

Comment: @P.Tillmann what if you need to group by more than one column?

Comment: this is such an elegant solution, thank!

Comment: Was looking through many pages trying to just find this simple counter. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 26):

One-liner:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('col').cumcount()
```

or

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('col').cumcount() + 1
```

if you want the counts to begin at 1.

Comment: If you want to start the counter at it is easier to use:
df['count'] = df.groupby('col').cumcount() + 1

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This does not count consecutive values, it counts total values.

Comment: This solution would count the last B as number 3, and not 1

Answer (score 24):

Based on the second answer you linked, assuming `s` is your series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df['block'] = (df['col'] != df['col'].shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby('block').transform(lambda x: range(1, len(x) + 1))


In [88]: df
Out[88]: 
  col  block  count
0   B      1      1
1   B      1      2
2   A      2      1
3   A      2      2
4   A      2      3
5   B      3      1
```

Comment: Really liked your method. But, how to do in case if grouping is done on multiple columns ?

Answer (score 13):

I like the answer by @chrisb but wanted to share my own solution, since some people might find it more readable and easier to use with similar problems....

1) Create a function that uses static variables

```
def rolling_count(val):
    if val == rolling_count.previous:
        rolling_count.count +=1
    else:
        rolling_count.previous = val
        rolling_count.count = 1
    return rolling_count.count
rolling_count.count = 0 #static variable
rolling_count.previous = None #static variable
```

2) apply it to your Series after converting to dataframe

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(s)
df['count'] = df['col'].apply(rolling_count) #new column in dataframe
```

**output of df**

```
  col  count
0   B      1
1   B      2
2   A      1
3   A      2
4   A      3
5   B      1
```

Comment: This is a great answer... How would you modify it to work if the rolling count was based on two fields - for example, 'cola' and 'colb'? In that case, if either changed I'd want to see a reset of the counter..  Thank you - this would save me a ton of work

Comment: Nice! This works for a dataframe with any number of other columns. @chrisb's solution will only work with one column in the dataframe (when I run it on my dataframe, I get an error that `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to do the same thing but filter on two columns, you can use this.

```
def count_consecutive_items_n_cols(df, col_name_list, output_col):
    cum_sum_list = [
        (df[col_name] != df[col_name].shift(1)).cumsum().tolist() for col_name in col_name_list
    ]
    df[output_col] = df.groupby(
        ["_".join(map(str, x)) for x in zip(*cum_sum_list)]
    ).cumcount() + 1
    return df

col_a col_b count
0   1     B     1
1   1     B     2
2   1     A     1
3   2     A     1
4   2     A     2
5   2     B     1
```