# count cumulative number of rows since a condition is et in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF that has two columns, Day, and Data, reading from a csv file.

[image]

After reading, I add 3 columns "Days with condition 0", 1, and 2. For example, for the columns 'Days with condition 2' I do this:

```
DF['Days with condition 2'] = ''
DF['Days with condition 2'][DF['Data']==2]=1
```

What I need to do and can't figure out is how to calculate 'Days since condition' 0,1,2. For example, the 'Days since condition 2' should display 11 in index 19, since that's the number of rows since the last condition was triggered (index 8). Is there any pandas function to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas: conditional rolling count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count)

Comment: in your example, what would be the value in "Days since condition" at index 8?   1?

Comment: It would be 0, before that NA

Comment: Sorry, i worded my question poorly.  What would you like it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your two original columns

```
   Day  Data
0     1     1
1     2     0
2     3     0
3     4     0
4     5     0
5     6     0
6     7     1
7     8     0
8     9     2
9    10     0
10   11     0
11   12     1
12   13     0
13   14     0
14   15     0
15   16     1
16   17     0
17   18     1
18   19     0
19   20     2
20   21     0
21   22     0
22   23     0
```

Here's how you could populate "Days with condition 2".  Filter for the 2s using boolean indexing.  Then we subtract our previous Day using shift().

The next couple of steps filters for the first occurrence of 2 and updates "Days with condition 2" equal to Day, but it could be whatever you want it to be

Then a fillna() to get rid of the NaNs.  The same pattern could be used for the other two columns you want to add

```
filter = (df["Data"] == 2) 
df.loc[filter,"Days with condition 2"] =  df[filter]["Day"] - df[filter]["Day"].shift(1)
filter = filter & (df["Days with condition 2"].isnull())
df.loc[filter,"Days with condition 2"] =  df[filter]["Day"]
df = df.fillna(0)
df
    Day  Data  Days with condition 2
0     1     1                      0
1     2     0                      0
2     3     0                      0
3     4     0                      0
4     5     0                      0
5     6     0                      0
6     7     1                      0
7     8     0                      0
8     9     2                      9
9    10     0                      0
10   11     0                      0
11   12     1                      0
12   13     0                      0
13   14     0                      0
14   15     0                      0
15   16     1                      0
16   17     0                      0
17   18     1                      0
18   19     0                      0
19   20     2                     11
20   21     0                      0
21   22     0                      0
22   23     0                      0
```