# python combine rows in dataframe and add up values

Tags: python

I have a dataframe:

```
 Type:  Volume:
 Q     10
 Q     20 
 T     10 
 Q     10
 T     20
 T     20
 Q     10
```

and I want to combine type T to one row and add up volume only if two(or more) Ts are consecutive

i.e. to :

```
 Q    10
 Q    20 
 T    10 
 Q    10 
 T    20+20=40
 Q    10
```

is there any way to achieve this? would `DataFrame.groupby` work?

Comment: This looks like it might start to address your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679091/4365003

Comment: I think that's kind of different...I want to combine rows instead of count them

Comment: ~~Wouldn't you just use a different aggregate function, then?~~

Comment: I cant find the aggregate function that does this... sry im new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help. This code can handle any number of consecutive 'T's, and you can even change which character to combine. I've added comments in the code to explain what it does.

https://pastebin.com/FakbnaCj

```
import pandas as pd

def combine(df):
    combined = [] # Init empty list
    length = len(df.iloc[:,0]) # Get the number of rows in DataFrame
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        num_elements = num_elements_equal(df, i, 0, 'T') # Get the number of consecutive 'T's
        if num_elements <= 1: # If there are 1 or less T's, append only that element to combined, with the same type
            combined.append([df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,1]])
        else: # Otherwise, append the sum of all the elements to combined, with 'T' type
            combined.append(['T', sum_elements(df, i, i+num_elements, 1)])
        i += max(num_elements, 1) # Increment i by the number of elements combined, with a min increment of 1
    return pd.DataFrame(combined, columns=df.columns) # Return as DataFrame

def num_elements_equal(df, start, column, value): # Counts the number of consecutive elements
    i = start
    num = 0
    while i < len(df.iloc[:,column]):
        if df.iloc[i,column] == value:
            num += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            return num
    return num

def sum_elements(df, start, end, column): # Sums the elements from start to end
    return sum(df.iloc[start:end, column])

frame = pd.DataFrame({"Type":   ["Q", "Q", "T", "Q", "T", "T", "Q"],
               "Volume": [10,   20,  10,  10,  20,  20,  10]})
print(combine(frame))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. May I ask how can I change this code if I got a dataframe with more than 2 columns, and I only want to add up the value of one column and leave the rest unchanged? i.e. instead of 'Type' and 'Volume', I got 'Type', 'Time', 'Volume' and ect, and I only want to add up the value for 'Volume'

Comment: When you append the element to the combined list (`a`) just put in `df.iloc[i,col]` where col is the column index of the 'Time' column. `combined.append([df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,1]])` becomes `combined.append([df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,1],df.iloc[i,2]])`, and `combined.append(['T', sum_elements(df, i, i+num_elements, 1)])` becomes `combined.append(['T', df.iloc[i,1], sum_elements(df, i, i+num_elements, 2)])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099924/how-to-combine-consecutive-data-in-a-dataframe-and-add-up-value

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the partial sums, here is a little trick to do that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Type":   ["Q", "Q", "T", "Q", "T", "T", "Q"],
                   "Volume": [10,   20,  10,  10,  20,  20,  10]})
s = np.diff(np.r_[0, df.Type == "T"])
s[s < 0] = 0
res = df.groupby(("Type", np.cumsum(s) - 1)).sum().loc["T"]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
   Volume
0      10
1      40
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099924/how-to-combine-consecutive-data-in-a-dataframe-and-add-up-value

Comment: @bing Is that the same question repeated?

Comment: Not exactly the same, the new dataframe got more than two columns