# Adding rows using timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, timestamp

I saw this code
[combine rows and add up value in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074742/combine-rows-and-add-up-value-in-dataframe),

but I want to add the values in cells for the same day, i.e. add all data for a day. how do I modify the code to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000],
                   'Time':['2012.05','2012.05','2012.05','2012.06','2012.06','2012.07'],
                   'Type':['Q','T','Q','T','T','Q'],
                   'Volume':[10,20,10,20,30,10]
                   })

df.assign(daily_volume = df.groupby('Time')['Volume'].transform('sum'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you. let us assume the type column is not there and I want to add the values in 'Volume' and 'daily_volume' for each month i.e for 2012.05 volume=10+20+10 and daily_volume= 40+40+40. instead of T used in the main post (link in the main question

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide dummy data & complete expected output