# How to combine consecutive data in a dataframe and add up value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe :

```
 Type:  Volume: Date:
 Q     10      2016.6.1
 Q     20      2016.6.1 
 T     10      2016.6.2 
 Q     10      2016.6.3
 T     20      2016.6.4
 T     20      2016.6.5
 Q     10      2016.6.6
```

Note that the date for the two consecutive T's are different, and I want to take the first date

and I want to combine type T to one row and add up volume only if two(or more) Ts are consecutive

i.e. to :

```
 Q     10      2016.6.1
 Q     20      2016.6.1 
 T     10      2016.6.2 
 Q     10      2016.6.3
 T     20+20=40 2016.6.4
 Q     10      2016.6.6
```

The code im using right now is:

```
df.groupby(by = [df.Type.ne('T').cumsum(),'Price', 'Time', 'Type'], as_index = False)['Volume'].sum()
```

However, this code only works when the date of the consecutive Ts are the same. Do you know how to combine consecutive T with different date, and only take the first date?

[image: dataframe: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Type":   ["Q", "Q", "T", "Q", "T", "T", "Q"],
                   "Volume": [10,   20,  10,  10,  20,  20,  10],
                   "Date":   ["2016-06-01", "2016-06-01", "2016-06-02", "2016-06-03",
                              "2016-06-04", "2016-06-05", "2016-06-06"]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

res = df.groupby(by = [df.Type.ne('T').cumsum(), 'Type'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': 'sum', 'Date': 'first'})
print(res)
```

Output:

```
  Type       Date  Volume
0    Q 2016-06-01      10
1    Q 2016-06-01      20
2    T 2016-06-02      10
3    Q 2016-06-03      10
4    T 2016-06-04      40
5    Q 2016-06-06      10
```

Comment: thanks, but instead of finding the aggregate value, I want to combine type 'T' only if there are two consecutive Ts

Comment: @bing Exactly two or more than one?

Comment: more than one, i.e. for Q T T Q T T T Q T => Q T Q T Q T

Comment: thank you for your answer. it works for this dataframe, however, if i got a dataframe as the table above (with more column: MidPrice, L1-BidPrice...) and I changed the code but it does not work - MidPrice, L1-BidPrice appear to be 0

Comment: @bing Well, your problem seems to keep changing. You just need to add the new columns in `.agg` according to how you want to aggregate each of them (`sum`, `first`, `count`, `mean`, etc.).

Comment: df.groupby(by = [df.Type.ne('T').cumsum(),'Price', 'Time', 'Type'], as_index = False)['Volume'].sum():     this code does what exactly I want except I cannot combine consecutive columns if their datetime are different

Comment: @bing What about `df.groupby(by = [df.Type.ne('T').cumsum(),'Price', 'Type'], as_index = False).agg({'Volume': 'sum', 'Time': 'first'})`? (you could add then the `count` aggregation kind of like I do to filter groups with just one element).

Comment: @bing No problem. Actually your method for grouping subsequences of `T`s was much better than mine. I've updated the answer with the final correct solution.