# Curious unapply of function with bigger pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

### UPDATED ISSUE

As asked, I provide a reproducible example. 
There are links to access a 1/6 of my [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7j94busuacr6tfs/DF_stackover?dl=0) (a serialized `pandas.DataFrame` object via `Pickle`) and a [`jupyter notebook`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oki6s335csd5p4g/Stackoverflow%20reproducible%20example.ipynb?dl=0) to have a reproducible code, where there is a sample of the dataframe where the function correctly applies and the bigger dataframe where it does not.

Notice dropbox gonna says a view is not avaiblable but the files are, tell me if not.

### ACIENT ISSUE, where the issue finally is not from `pool.map()`

Linked to this [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924136/difference-of-days-between-two-dates-until-a-condition-is-met/58925896?noredirect=1#comment104137425_58925896) , I use this method on a sample of the dataframe to see if it does the thing right, and it is the case as the following:

```
m = dfsample.Result.eq('Win')
s = m.shift().cumsum()
dfsample['gap_in_days'] = dfsample.groupby(['name', s])['Gap done'].cumsum() #"Expected Gap" in the linked topic
dfsample['nb_of_games'] = dfsample.assign(nb_of_games = 1).groupby('name')['nb_of games'].apply(lambda x:x.shift().cumsum()).fillna(0)
dfsample['gap_in_numbers'] = dfsample.assign(nb = 1).groupby(['name',s])['nb'].cumsum()
```

It renders what I expect:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|    Player |   Result   |        Date         | Gap done | gap_in_days | nb_of_games | gap_in_numbers |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| K2000     | Lose       | 2015-11-13 13:42:00 |      0.0 |         0.0 |           0 | -1 *           |
| K2000     | Lose       | 2016-03-23 16:40:00 |    131.0 |       131.0 |           1 | 1              |
| K2000     | Lose       | 2016-05-16 19:17:00 |     54.0 |       185.0 |           2 | 2              |
| K2000     | Win        | 2016-06-09 19:36:00 |     54.0 |       239.0 |           3 | 3              |
| K2000     | Win        | 2016-06-30 14:05:00 |     54.0 |        54.0 |           4 | 1              |
| K2000     | Lose       | 2016-07-29 16:20:00 |     29.0 |        29.0 |           5 | 2              |
| K2000     | Win        | 2016-10-08 17:48:00 |     29.0 |        58.0 |           6 | 3              |
| Kssis     | Lose       | 2007-02-25 15:05:00 |      0.0 |         0.0 |           0 | 1 *            |
| Kssis     | Lose       | 2007-04-25 6:07:00  |     59.0 |        59.0 |           1 | 1              |
| Kssis     | Not-ranked | 2007-06-01 16:54:00 |     37.0 |        96.0 |           2 | 2              |
| Kssis     | Lose       | 2007-09-09 14:33:00 |     99.0 |       195.0 |           3 | 3              |
| Kssis     | Lose       | 2008-04-06 16:27:00 |    210.0 |       405.0 |           4 | 4              |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

To explain the data, `Gap done` is the number of days between two different games. `gap_in_days` is the number of days until the player won a game. `nb_of_games` is obivous I guess. `gap_in_numbers` is the number of games played until the player won. 
 **Notes: about the values with a *. I know these are weird results, but as I told to Andy L. this is correctable. I just replace by 0 when `nb_of_games` is 0. Besides, I show you it, because if you test you will obviously see it and get interrogations.**

Now, when I apply the same thing in function with `pool.map(function , iterable)` it does not work, while applying the same function on the sample of dataframe `dfsample` is totally fine.

The function is the following:

```
def gap_nb(df):
    s = mask_result(df)
    df['gap_in_numbers'] = df.assign(nb = 1).groupby(['name',s])['nb'].cumsum()
    return df
```

and the function `mask_result` is:

```
def mask_result(df):
    mask = df.Result.eq('P')
    s = mask.shift().cumsum()
    return s
```

Then after I use it with `pool.map(function, iterable)` as

```
dfs = pool.map(gap_nb , dfs) #where dfs is a list of slices of a big dataframe
```

it simply renders the column `gap_in_numbers` with `1` as:

```
+----------------+
| gap_in_numbers |
+----------------+
|              0 |
|              1 |
|              1 |
|              1 |
|              1 |
|            ... |
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

I tried to find some ways, like to use `assign()` in another function, then apply the `cumsum()` in another one, but it returns the same thing.

So, can anyone tell me why ?

---

Pandas version: 0.23.4 Python version: 3.7.4

---

Example data to play with (without the last column)

```
import io
s = '''Player,Result,Date,Gap,done,gap_in_days,nb_of_games
K2000,Lose,2015-11-13,13:42:00,0.0,0.0,0
K2000,Lose,2016-03-23,16:40:00,131.0,131.0,1
K2000,Lose,2016-05-16,19:17:00,54.0,185.0,2
K2000,Win,2016-06-09,19:36:00,54.0,239.0,3
K2000,Win,2016-06-30,14:05:00,54.0,54.0,4
K2000,Lose,2016-07-29,16:20:00,29.0,29.0,5
K2000,Win,2016-10-08,17:48:00,29.0,58.0,6
Kssis,Lose,2007-02-25,15:05:00,0.0,0.0,0
Kssis,Lose,2007-04-25,6:07:00,59.0,59.0,1
Kssis,Not-ranked,2007-06-01,16:54:00,37.0,96.0,2
Kssis,Lose,2007-09-09,14:33:00,99.0,195.0,3
Kssis,Lose,2008-04-06,16:27:00,210.0,405.0,4'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
```

Comment: In `gap_nb` should `df.assign(nb = 1).groupby(['name',s])['nb'].cumsum()` be `df.assign(nb = 1).groupby(['Player',s])['nb_of_games'].cumsum()` to match your example df? Also in `mask_result` should `df.Result.eq('P')` be `df.Result.eq('Win')`??

Comment: Do the two functions work as you expect when you pass your example dataframe to them (without using multiprocessing)?

Comment: @wii you're right for one thing, I changed `df.Result.eq('P')` by `df.Result.eq('Win')`, that's just example are above all illustrative, real data are huger and not in English. <br>
And for the first question, this is not interesting to cumsum `nb_of_games` for `gap_nb` because it makes a wrong result simply. <br>
And the function which I have problem only has with multiprocessing. Strangely not others based on the same thing like `gap_in_days` that I did not write in the topic because it works fine.

Comment: Using your example DataFrame and `with Pool(5) as p:  print(p.map(gap_nb, [df]))` I get the same result as passing the DataFrame to `gap_nb` without using `multiprocessing`.  I get good results with `p.map(gap_nb, [df.iloc[:7],df.iloc[7:]])` ... So it seems you haven't provided sufficient information - please read [mcve]. we need to be able to test and recreate your problem.

Comment: @wii, maybe the problem occurs when the df is splitted, because this is actually the case. And this is rightly splitted.

Comment: Certainly if you split is across `groupby` boundaries you will get inaccurate results.

Comment: Without a suffcient [mcve] it's not possible to recreate your problem. If it is due to the way you are splitting up the Dataframe perhaps try - `pool.map(gap_nb, [thing[1] for thing in df.groupby('Player')]))`

Comment: @wii I gonna see how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: @wii I provided a reproducible dataset and code.

Comment: I provided what I thought was an answer, is it what you were looking for?

Comment: @wwii it did not correspond to the results I expected, I did a list of dataframes where each one is for an unique `Player`. The production of this list is terribly high in cost (actually that's the longest, and very long one, operation in it), but it gives the result I expect, then I concatenate with `pd.concat(the_high_cost_list_of_dfs)`.