# Assign increasing number based on common number in a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

There is a column in my dataset that looks like that:

```
col1
100
100
100
101
101
102
102
103
103
103
103
104
104
```

I want to create a column that gives an increasing number per group. Specifically, where is `100` in the `col1` there will be `01`. The next `100` will have `02` and so on. When it reaches to the row that has `101` it will perform similarly:`01`, the next `101`, `02` like it did with `100`.

I tried it and I can't make it do what I am planning:
I have to make a new column first

```
df['nc'] = df.groupby(col1)
```

which is wrong.

Desired output:

```
    col1   nc
    100    01
    100    02
    100    03
    101    01
    101    02
    102    01
    102    02
    103    01
    103    02
    103  ........ and so on
    103
    104
    104
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your logic. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50834192/edit) your question with an example of your desired output?

Comment: I updated it. It's clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Pandas: conditional rolling count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for this.

```
df['nc'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()+1
```

Which gives:

```
   col1  nc
0   100   1
1   100   2
2   100   3
3   101   1
4   101   2
5   102   1
6   102   2
7   103   1
8   103   2
9   103   3
10  103   4
11  104   1
12  104   2
```

You can format the numbers as necessary if you require leading zeros.

Comment: I indeed need the leading zeros, include it in your answer if you know how to do it.

Comment: Just use `(df.groupby('col1').cumcount()+1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)`.