# Sequence for an event based on time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sequence, pandas-groupby

I have a time series data which I want to find the sequence for a certain event based on the time and another category value.

```
Example:
Time    Event    Category    Seq
1         A         1         1 
2         A         1         2  
3         B         1         1
4         B         2         1
5         C         1         1
6         A         1         1
```

I searched and found that I can use groupby and cumcount() to do this but I'm not able to achieve the sequences at time 1 and time 6 in the above example (Event A of same category and different time should have a new sequence number, my code continues the sequence and outputs as 3)

```
df['sequence']=df.groupby('Event').cumcount() + 1
```

Related Question:

[Pandas: conditional rolling count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count) (considers the one-columnar case)

Comment: Grouping by `'Event'` and cumulative counting should give you `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3]` as your new `sequence` column. If that is not what you expect, what do you expect instead?

Comment: I need the sequence to be grouped by the Event, Category and time. For example -  For event A, category 1 the sequence for time 1 and 2 is 1 & 2 respectively. And the next occurrence of A1 at time 6 should be 1 again. Also for event B, for category 1 and 2 at times 3 and 4 should both be 1. I hope my explanation is clear now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Your question is related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count but since you ask for a multi-columnar case I will add answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this. Given this data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Event': list('AABBCA'),
                   'Category': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]})
```

you want to groupby `'Event'` and `'Category'` and then cumcount. In order to restart your count you can compare the consecutive rows by using `shift(1)` and persist the information using `any(axis=1)` and `cumsum()`. The total command then reads

```
>>> df['Seq'] = df.groupby((df[['Event', 'Category']] != df[['Event', 'Category']].shift(1)).any(axis=1).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
>>> df
   Time Event  Category  Seq
0     1     A         1    1
1     2     A         1    2
2     3     B         1    1
3     4     B         2    1
4     5     C         1    1
5     6     A         1    1
```

Note: The `'Time'` column seems to be only your index and might be skipped. Though I included it.