# Python Pandas : Conditional rolling count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Here is my **input dataframe**:

```
type
a   
a   
a   
a   
a   
b   
b   
a   
a   
a
```

This is my **expected output**:

```
type,   id
a   ,   1
a   ,   2
a   ,   3
a   ,   4
a   ,   5
b   ,   5
b   ,   5
a   ,   6
a   ,   7
a   ,   8
```

I need to generate `ID` column based on `'type'` column. I have two types `'a'` & `'b'`.. as long as it is `'a'` I want to increment `ID`. If `'b'`, keep previous `'a'` `ID`. How can I do this in a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count

Comment: @petezurich, There should be a duplicate somewhere, but I don't think that's the one.

Comment: No.. my query is different.

Comment: I'am wondering how this question fall under `too broad` category?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, I think it's groupthink (the first guy chose it, others follow). This is *probably* a duplicate, I just couldn't find it. It could be no MCVE too, but not too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can count the cumulative sum of a Boolean series indicating when your series equals a value:

```
df['id'] = df['type'].eq('a').cumsum()
```

Comment: what happens to type 'b' ?

Comment: Where you have type `b`, `df['type'].eq('a')` gives `False`, which is equal to `0`, `cumsum` therefore works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this way, Obviously @jpp answer is coolest one. But I approached like this just to give an idea.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','a','a','a']})
df['type']= df.groupby('col1').cumcount()+1
df.loc[df['col1']=='b','type']=np.NaN
df['type']=df['type'].ffill()
print df
```

O/P

```
  col1  type
0    a   1.0
1    a   2.0
2    a   3.0
3    a   4.0
4    a   5.0
5    b   5.0
6    b   5.0
7    a   6.0
8    a   7.0
9    a   8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame is `df`:

```
df[df=='a'].expanding().count()
```