# Conditional count of cumulative sum Dataframe - Loop through columns

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, cumsum

Im trying to compute a cumulative sum with a reset within a dataframe, based on the sign of each values. The idea is to the same exercise for each column separately.

For example, let's assume I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1],'B':[1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

For each column, I want to compute the cumulative sum until I find a change in sign; in which case, the sum should be reset to 1. For the example above, I am expecting the following result:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A_cumcount':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3],'B_cumcount':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]})
```

Similar issue has been discussed here: [Pandas: conditional rolling count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count)

I have tried the following code:

```
nb_col=len(df.columns) #number of columns in dataframe


for i in range(0,int(nb_col)): #Loop through the number of columns in the dataframe

    name=df.columns[i] #read the column name
    name=name+'_cumcount' 


    #add column for the calculation
    df=df.reindex(columns=np.append(df.columns.values, [name])) 

    df=df[df.columns[nb_col+i]]=df.groupby((df[df.columns[i]] != df[df.columns[i]].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
```

My question is, is there a way to avoid this for loop? So I can avoid appending a new column each time and make the computation faster. Thank you

Answers received (all working fine):
From @nixon
 `df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount()+1).add_suffix('_cumcount')`

From @jezrael
 `df1 = (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1).add_suffix('_cumcount'))`

From @Scott Boston:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.diff().bfill().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in pandas need loop, e.g. by `apply`:

```
df1 = (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
         .add_suffix('_cumcount'))
print (df1)
    A_cumcount  B_cumcount
0            1           1
1            2           2
2            3           1
3            1           2
4            2           3
5            1           1
6            2           2
7            3           3
8            4           1
9            1           2
10           2           3
11           3           1
```

Comment: @CTXR - btw, what is reason for not use loops per columns? Big data?

Comment: exactly, the dataframe is quite big!

Comment: @CTXR You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615600/get-cumulative-count-per-2d-array) for another faster solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by grouping by where the changes in the sequence occur by doing `x.diff().ne(0).cumsum()`, and using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) over the groups:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
                    .cumcount()+1).add_suffix('_cumcount')

        A_cumcount  B_cumcount
0            1           1
1            2           2
2            3           1
3            1           2
4            2           3
5            1           1
6            2           2
7            3           3
8            4           1
9            1           2
10           2           3
11           3           1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.diff().bfill().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
```

Output:

```
    A  B
0   1  1
1   2  2
2   3  1
3   1  2
4   2  3
5   1  1
6   2  2
7   3  3
8   4  1
9   1  2
10  2  3
11  3  1
```