# modifying conditionnally a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I try to modify the value of cells in a dataframe, conditionnal to their value.
the dataframe dataTrad(50k, 20) as 21 columns, one of which is called 'reindex'.
I want to bring the value of any 'reindex' cell down to 0 as soon as its original value is lower than a variable (mlp).

I tried : `dataTrad[i, 'reindex'][dataTrad[i, 'reindex'] < mlp] = 0` with a loop on i with the range(len(dataTrad)),
as well as `dataTrad.loc[(dataTrad.reindex < malp),'reindex']=0`, but none of these two methods worked.

In my precise example, I had mlp = 60 len(dataTrad) = 57830

What do I do wrong, and how could I solve this ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include a small sample of your data along with your desired results. Take a look at [how-to-make-good-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what the 'reindex' column is, is it a counter that you want to 'reset' each time 'mpl' reaches a certain point, or a value that you want to use *unless 'mlp' reaches a certain point.*

For the second, a simple apply / lambda combo should do what you need, something like this:

```
dataTrad['reindex'] = dataTrad.apply(lambda row: row['reindex'] if x > row['mlp'] else 0)
```

Otherwise, a cumulative rolling count that resets is 'slightly' more complicated, but [is covered pretty well here if you need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count).

Comment: Thanks. I get an error as follows : 
File "<ipython-input-320-c43f81361c8b>", line 1
    dataTrad['reindex'] = dataTrad.apply(lamba row: row['reindex'] if x > row['mlp'] else 0)
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: woops! I'd written 'lamba' not 'lambda' which would definitely cause an error since 'lamba' isn't a thing (have edited now, let me know how it runs)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
dataTrad['reindex'] = dataTrad['reindex'].apply(lambda x: 0 if (x<mlp) else x)
```

I'm sure there should be another way, like a `inplace` parameter but try this for now

Let me know if it works :)