# Save for loop data to a new column in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am calculating a value for a new column and I want to save this data for each time step. My data is hourly time series data with a column of 0 or 1 indicating if precipitation is not rain or rain accordingly. I then want to create a column that tells me how many hours (each row of data is 1 hour) have passed since it last rained (sees a 1 in the rain column).

```
hours_since_rainfall = 0
df['hours_since_rainfall'] = []

for rain in df['rain']:
if rain == 0 : 
    hours_since_rainfall += 1
else : 
    hours_since_rainfall = 0
print(hours_since_rainfall)
```

The print function gives me accurate data readout. How do I save this to a new column in my dataframe? I have tried all sorts of append, concat, and I just cannot get the data frame to populate. Here were some of my attempts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(hours_since_rainfall)    
df['hours_since_rainfall'] = df.append(hours_since_rainfall)    
df['hours_since_rainfall'] = hours_since_rainfall
```

The data I am trying to achieve:

```
date                  rain  hours_since_rain
2005-10-15 16:00:00   1      0
2005-10-15 17:00:00   1      0
2005-10-15 18:00:00   0      1
2005-10-15 19:00:00   0      2
2005-10-15 20:00:00   0      3
2005-10-15 21:00:00   0      4
2005-10-15 22:00:00   1      0
```

Comment: Append `hour_since_rainfall` in a list and assign that list to `df['hours_since_rainfall']`.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to [build a list](https://realpython.com/python-append/)?

Comment: Not from a for loop. All I have been able to do is print out the list. I have been googling and reading forums on this for hours. Any help would be appreciated. It seems like it should be so simple but I can't get it to work no matter what I have tried.

Comment: Can you include a sample of your source dataframe (`df.head(10).to_dict()` or so) in your question? Can you also mock up a few rows of what you want your resulting dataframe to look like?

Comment: I updated my entry to show the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to me that you're really trying to create a [Pandas: conditional rolling count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25119524/15497888).

Except when the `rain` value is `1` you want zeros and when the `rain` value is `0` you want the rolling count.

To do this, you can get the rolling total for all groups in `rain`, then go back through the DataFrame and set the `hours_since_rainfall` values to `0` where `rain` is `1`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': {
        0: '2005-10-15 16:00:00', 1: '2005-10-15 17:00:00',
        2: '2005-10-15 18:00:00', 3: '2005-10-15 19:00:00',
        4: '2005-10-15 20:00:00', 5: '2005-10-15 21:00:00',
        6: '2005-10-15 22:00:00', 7: '2005-10-15 23:00:00',
        8: '2005-10-16 00:00:00', 9: '2005-10-16 01:00:00'
    },
    'rain': {
        0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0
    }
})

df['hours_since_rainfall'] = df.groupby([(df['rain'] != df['rain'].shift()).cumsum()]) \
                                 .cumcount() + 1
df.loc[df['rain'] == 1, 'hours_since_rainfall'] = 0
print(df)
```

---

Alternatively, you can conditionally `transform` based on the `rain` value.

If the first value in the group is a 0 (all of the values in the group are 0), you can replace the series with the `range` from `1` to `len + 1`.

If the first value in the group is a 1 (all the values in the group are 1), you can replace it with `[0] * len` or, basically, an equal length series of zeros.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': {
        0: '2005-10-15 16:00:00', 1: '2005-10-15 17:00:00',
        2: '2005-10-15 18:00:00', 3: '2005-10-15 19:00:00',
        4: '2005-10-15 20:00:00', 5: '2005-10-15 21:00:00',
        6: '2005-10-15 22:00:00', 7: '2005-10-15 23:00:00',
        8: '2005-10-16 00:00:00', 9: '2005-10-16 01:00:00'
    },
    'rain': {
        0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0
    }
})

df['hours_since_rainfall'] = df \
    .groupby([(df['rain'] != df['rain'].shift()).cumsum()])['rain'] \
    .transform(lambda x: range(1, len(x) + 1) if x.iloc[0] == 0 else [0] * len(x))
print(df)
```

Both Produce:

```py
                  date  rain  hours_since_rainfall
0  2005-10-15 16:00:00     1                     0
1  2005-10-15 17:00:00     1                     0
2  2005-10-15 18:00:00     0                     1
3  2005-10-15 19:00:00     0                     2
4  2005-10-15 20:00:00     0                     3
5  2005-10-15 21:00:00     0                     4
6  2005-10-15 22:00:00     1                     0
7  2005-10-15 23:00:00     1                     0
8  2005-10-16 00:00:00     0                     1
9  2005-10-16 01:00:00     0                     2
```

As Dict:

```py
{'date': {0: '2005-10-15 16:00:00', 1: '2005-10-15 17:00:00',
          2: '2005-10-15 18:00:00', 3: '2005-10-15 19:00:00',
          4: '2005-10-15 20:00:00', 5: '2005-10-15 21:00:00',
          6: '2005-10-15 22:00:00', 7: '2005-10-15 23:00:00',
          8: '2005-10-16 00:00:00', 9: '2005-10-16 01:00:00'},
 'rain': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0,
          5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 'hours_since_rainfall': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3,
                          5: 4, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 2}}
```

Comment: When the count starts again it continues at 5 instead of resetting at 1. Sorry if I did not make that clear. How do I reset the count to 1?

Comment: You were clear. I knew the hours since rain should reset to 0 in each group of 1s, but your provided data didn't include the case where this happened, so I missed it my testing. It should work as expected now.